# transform character to a number in R

Tags: r

I loaded a data big set with read_delim(), since there I have the possibility to skip the first 4 rows of the data set which is not important for me. The data set is separated by ";". My Problem is the following: 
I have some numbers like

```
-0,000364929204806685

0,00367021351121366

-0,0184237491339445
```

as you can see this numbers are seperated by commas. Therefore if i change the  type of it to "numeric", during the loading phase, i get a formatting error like -3.649292e+14 for the first number. Thus i have to load the data as characters. 
But now I am not able to do numeric calculations. as.numeric() doesen't work.

Is there any possibility to change this characters to numeric?

Thanks 
Matthias

Comment: You can try `as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", "32,11"))`

Comment: Try to load the data using `read_csv2`

Comment: where i should use this?

Comment: If all values in the file use , instead of . then you can specify this in the read.delim. i.e. `read_delim(file, dec = ',')`

Comment: I tried to load the data by read_csv2, but then i am not able to skip the first rows of the data. In the original data i have Things like accelerationx:-0.0036. as a entry. I remote the strings afterwards, therefore i have to load it as a character

Comment: You can still use the `skip` argument with `utils::read.csv2` to skip the first rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for help, it can be solved by using `gsub()`. In the upper example:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", Dat[1,12]))
```

provides:

```
-0.0003649292
```